# Erro ao tentar validar @CPF e @CNPJ com Hibernate jSf2

Tags: jsf, hibernate, primefaces, java-ee

Boa noite tenho um projeto de um sistema em JavaEE com JSF2 Primefaces.
Estou usando os mapeamentos @CPF e @CNPJ do hibernate, no mesmo atributo.
Mas esta dando erro "WARN: HV000129: EL expression '${value}' references an unknown property"
Essa é parte do codigo do model`@CNPJ(groups =JuridicaGroup.class)
    @CPF(groups = FisicaGroup.class)
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "doc_receita_federal", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getDocumentoReceitaFederal() {
        return documentoReceitaFederal;
    }`
 Gostaria receber por favor a ajuda, pesquisei na internet mas nada, só respostas vagas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom pessoal quanto ao erro acima esta resolvido, atualizei para o hibernate 5.2.4
e alterei o código  beans.xml`<interceptors>
        <class>com.soulsoftware.sisgep.util.jpa.TransactionInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>`